# windows makefile failed on stockfish (a chess program)

Tags: windows, github, makefile, compilation, stockfish

It's the first time I makefile on windows, and I installed the make command via chocolatey.
To some extent it works, but the compilation failed, shows:

```
C:\Users\87952\Desktop\Stockfish-master\Stockfish-master\src>make build
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.
Makefile:24: pipe: No error
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.
Makefile:381: pipe: No error
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.
Makefile:443: pipe: No error
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.
Makefile:488: pipe: No error
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.
Makefile:519: pipe: Bad file descriptor
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.
Makefile:551: pipe: Bad file descriptor
'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
curl was unexpected at this time.
shasum was unexpected at this time.
"Default net: "
-f was unexpected at this time.
make: *** [Makefile:832: net] Error 255
```

I also tried to complete the parameters specifying architecture and compiler,but nothing changed.
So could anyone tell me what's wrong and how to fix it?
Here is the link to the program: [stockfish](https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish)

Now I changed to compile it on cygwin, it made progress, but compilation still failed:

```
/tmp/ccUfH6bQ.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccUfH6bQ.s:6: Warning: .type pseudo-op used outside of .def/.endef: ignored.
/tmp/ccUfH6bQ.s:6: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `g'
/tmp/ccUfH6bQ.s:11: Warning: .type pseudo-op used outside of .def/.endef: ignored.
/tmp/ccUfH6bQ.s:11: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `g'
/tmp/ccUfH6bQ.s:16: Warning: .type pseudo-op used outside of .def/.endef: ignored.
/tmp/ccUfH6bQ.s:16: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `g'
make[2]: *** [/tmp/ccXGdOpL.mk:2: /tmp/stockfish.exe.wUSNQg.ltrans0.ltrans.o] Error 1
lto-wrapper: fatal error: make returned 2 exit status
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:930: stockfish.exe] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/87952/Desktop/Stockfish-master/Stockfish-master/src'
make: *** [Makefile:797: build] Error 2
```

What does the error code mean and how to fix it?

Comment: It seems that Makefile references Unix commands, so it's probably not easy to run it under Windows. You can try to run it using Cygwin/MinGW or WSL instead.

Comment: Thank you, now I change to compile on cygwin but it still failed, can you have a look and tell me what is wrong this time? @raspy

Comment: You haven't shown us the compile command that caused these errors so it's hard to say for sure but I suspect that this project is not really set up to work on Windows, even with Cygwin.  However the documentation says: _In general it is recommended to run make help to see a list of make targets with corresponding descriptions_ and also _When not using the Makefile to compile (for instance, with Microsoft MSVC) you need to manually set/unset some switches in the compiler command line; see file types.h for a quick reference_.  I assume you already used both those facilities?

Comment: @MadScientist the make help command just show some supported target, architecture and compiler. I tried different parameters at first, but after siwtching to cygwin, I actually just used ` make -build ` , and after seeing your comment, I tried some parameters , and changing compiler from gcc to mingw make it compiled successfully. Now I'm confusing about why one compiler would work but the othe would not. Can you tell mr some reasons that could cause this kind of problem?

Comment: Not really.  I don't do Windows.  Maybe someone who knows about Windows can help.